# libgcc_s_sjlj-1 missing from compiled file in MinGW C++11

Tags: c++, windows, c++11

I am using the latest version of MinGW on Windows 7. I have written some code in SFML, and when I tried to compile and execute it, it gives me an error saying that I am missing libgcc_s_sjlj-1. I have checked this place out and added -static-libgcc to the command line, but even with that it still doesn't work. Any ideas? Here is the batch file that compiles and runs the code.

```
@ECHO OFF
@echo Calibrating...
g++ -o SFMLTest main.cpp -std=c++11 -static-libgcc -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics
@echo Finished! Running...
.\SFMLTest
```

EDIT: Even after removing all the files and starting again from scratch, this issue still persists. Can any of you help?

Comment: Try including libg++.

Comment: `-static-libstdc++` may help.  You could always just copy the DLL files to where you're trying to run the program.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried that, but now I get a different error: something about how the procedure entry point __gxx_personality_sj0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++ -6.dll. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cinch It says it cannot find libg++ for some reason.

Comment: The really weird thing is, I have another program with the EXACT same code in the batch file as this program, and that works perfectly. With this one I keep getting errors left and right. Does this work when it wants to or something?